# How do I find-replace text that is line-broken and indented randomly?

Tags: text-editing, ics

I have a .ICS document that I opened in Notepad.

When exporting the file, the calendar system watermarked every event description with a sentence. For a placeholder, I'll use:

```
This is a placeholder sentence with a web url http://example.com/null/.
```

I need to remove this sentence from a very long text file using only text editors that don't mess with indentation or formatting, because ICS's text format needs to be computer-readable.

Here's my problem. Lines are limited to 75 characters in ICS so the file ended up looking something like this:

```
DESCRIPTION: .................................. This is a placeholder senten
 ce with a web url http://example.com/null/.
DESCRIPTION: .......... This is a placeholder sentence with a web url http:/
 /example.com/null/.
DESCRIPTION: ......................................... This is a placeholder
  sentence with a web url http://example.com/null/.
```

The program broke off the sentence if it exceeded 75 characters and added a single-space indent on the next line. This, I assume, is for machine readability.

Problem is, that extra space voids any and all find-and-replace functions that I know how to use. It's random, it breaks up words, and I'm not sure what to do.

I need to use some sort of function or possibly a script that can ignore the linebreak AND indent. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to rebuild the full lines. A simple filter is a couple of line of C, but is pretty difficult in a script - I couldn't even get `sed` to do it, and it does most things. If it's only one file you may be able to find a binary editor which will do it (I was able to use `frhed`, but with difficulty). The Linux `bbe` command works (`bbe -b '/\n/:2' -e 's/\n //g'`), but I can't find a Windows port.

Comment: @AFH well, I better find a workaround for this. I'm in no position to be messing around with system commands.

Comment: Just found a simple answer for single files: `notepad++`. In **Extended** match mode you can find and replace (by blank) all occurrences of `\n `. I always use this instead of `notepad`, but forgot about extended search mode. You can easily obtain it as a [Portable App](http://portableapps.com/apps).

Comment: How can I get it to ignore the extra space? Is there a filter or something I can use? @AFH

Comment: I just told you: search for _new-line space_.

Comment: @AFH Okay, that seems to mess with the other blocks of text in the file, voiding the format. Is there a way to search for a sentence with an anomaly inside it?

Comment: Not that I know of. I can only think of removing _new-line space_, deleting the lines you want to remove, then re-inserting them with a regular expression substitution, replacing `(.{75})` with `\1\n `.

Comment: @AFH Ah, this is going to be difficult. ICS uses the _new-line space_ every time a line exceeds 75 chars, which includes other parts of the description that I'm not allowed to alter. I need to isolate _new-line space_ to this sentence somehow. Or perhaps, could I do a search for `This is ...(wildcard)... example.com/null.`, something that includes the sentence but doesn't explicitly reference the text in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

**Caution** at the outset: Work on a copy of the file and be **sure** about the line  breaks (some files have a carriage return and line feed):

You could search this site and read up on JREPL.BAT by dbenham or you could try out this hack on a copy of the file **assuming**:

a) Your .ICS file is a text file;

b) You only need to do this infrequently;

c) The DESCRIPTION **never** wraps onto the next line;

In Microsoft Word: highlight all the text (Ctrl+A) then open the find and replace dialogue using Ctrl+H on the keyboard:

**Step_1**
To find line breaks, type in the find box: "^l "
(include the space after the lowercase L)

**Step_2**
In the replace box, type nothing.

**Step_3**
Click on replace all.

**Step_4**
Ctrl+click **to the left of** each placeholder line that you wish to remove, then press delete.  (You could use the macro facility to do this automatically if this whole procedure works for you in general.)

OR you can use your usual tools to delete the placeholders.

**Step_5**
Save as a .txt file then rename it to .ICS

Comment: That's my problem. It doesn't split on the same word.

Comment: I have edited my suggestion to remove the line breaks and space

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Word doesn't seem to accept ^l as a valid search argument. (Word 2013)

Comment: Do a Find and Replace action like this in Word 2013:  
(1) Press these two keys together on the keyboard: Ctrl+H  
; (2) Click on "More"   
; (3) Click on "Special"  
; (4) Click on "Manual Line Break" (or click on "Paragraph Mark" if that is what your file contains).

You should now see ^l (or ^p) in the find and replace criteria.